# I'm trying to expand every UITableViewCell in a UITableView recursively by inserting the cells into the table, the cells aren't expanding correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

The table starts off with "collapsed" parent cells (the array representing this is what is first passed to the function). Each cell is represented in the array by an `NSDictionary`. Each parent cell has an array of child cells, and each child cell their array of child cells, etc. If a cell has no children, the "children" `key` in the dictionary is set to an empty `NSMutableArray`.

The goal of this function is to take an `NSMutableArray` representing the `tableView` with no expanded cells and expand each cell and it's children recursively (think a comment thread on Reddit) while adding the expanded cells to the original array accordingly. It works but, the cells aren't expanded correctly for some reason. Some are expanded and some aren't, it's odd. Any ideas?

```
- (void)expandCells:(NSMutableArray *)comments
{
    for (NSDictionary *thread in comments)
    {
        // recursive loop using each child in the root's child array
        NSMutableArray *children = [thread objectForKey:@"children"];
        if (children && [children count] > 0)
        {
            [self expandCells:children];

            // indexPath of root of current thread
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[comments indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:thread] inSection:0];
            NSUInteger count = indexPath.row + 1;
            NSMutableArray *newCellIndexes = [NSMutableArray array];

            for (NSDictionary *child in children)
            {
                //[newCellIndexes addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];

                // a copy of self.tableCells first passed to this function,
                // since you cannot modify an array while iterating over it
                [self.tableCells insertObject:child atIndex:count++];
            }

            //[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newCellIndexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is exactly described in the error. You are mutating the array while iterating through it. You say that in the first iteration, you pass in self.tableCells. so self.tableCells == comments, and while enumerating comments, you add objects to self.tableCells, thus mutating it. You cannot add objects to an array that you are enumerating through. consider storing the cells in another data structure.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can see the title I edited but that's not the problem I'm having anymore, I edited the post to remove anything about that. Now it's just that the outcome isn't as expected.

Comment: Yeah, you edited it while I was writing my response and posting it, literally finished the response within 30 seconds of you changing it. Post photos of what you are experiencing and the code for display, as this code sample is for your old question and only pertains to your data source manipulation, not the UI.

Comment: How unlikely was that? Sorry man, haha. Well, the code to display them is just the usual cellForRowAtIndexPath, where the key "level" determines the indentation level. It's up to this expand function to take the array of comments and insert them in the array used by cellForRowAtIndexPath in the right place with the right "level".

Comment: Here's a link to the [actual comments,](http://pastebin.com/ixBRcPu6) as they should look (data straight from Reddit, no issues here), and here's the comments [after being passed through this function](http://pastebin.com/eMYPWMT4). I can't make any sense of it except that the problem is that it's assigning comments on the same level with descending "level" values.